# Android Grid Formation

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I am looking to accomplish something like this in my app. A grid of 3 items in a row.
If there are only two or one item in the last row it should stack next to each other and align to the left and leave the second and the last as empty.

[image]

My Main Concern is how to handle this via code for the content that is sent from the server via an API and loop through and build this layout dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add to your gridview layout this line

```
 android:numColumns="3"
```

if you have 5 elements on your gridview adapter there will be 3 items in one row, on the second row there will be 2 items aligned to the left.

Comment: is grid view the best way to achieve this layout ?

Comment: how do i achieve the adding of the content dynamically bcos i am not sure if i will have 5 or 55 elements.

Comment: yeah the gridview is the best way to do it, you will not have to deal with the size of the screen, all you have to do is to integrate the gridview and prepare the it's adapter.
EDIT: you need to create gridview adapter to add dynamic items, many tutorials on the web can show you how to do it easily ;)